# toHaveBeenCalled() returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

As far as I understand, the `.toHaveBeenCalled()` Matcher of jasmine returns a Promise which is resolved when the function has been called. Actually for me, it returns undefined:

```
it('should show the first entries', () => {
  expect(contentfulService.first)
    .toHaveBeenCalled()
    .then(() => {
      expect(component.entries).toBe(entriesMock);
    });
});
```

The `first` method of the contentfulService is spied on like this:

```
contentfulService = TestBed.get(ContentfulService);
spyOn(contentfulService, 'first').and.callThrough();
```

The spec fails telling me:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I double checked it. It's definitely the result of `toHaveBeenCalled()` that returns undefined. Why? Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: which version of jasmine you use?

Comment: Where did you see it returns a promise? on https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#toHaveBeenCalled I see it's indeed supposed to return undefined.

Comment: vscode showed me the typings and autocompletion results of `@types/jasminewd2`, and not `@types/jasmine` what would have been right afais. In jasminewd2 typings, there is a Promise as result of the `toHaveBeenCalled` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toHaveBeenCalled` is an assertion method (like `toBe` or `toEqual`).  It is a synchronous method that fails the test if the mock has not been called and it returns undefined.

Usually you call it at the end of the test to verify your code did what it was supposed to.  It is not meant to be used for flow control.

Comment: thanks - I found out the problem why I thought I could use the promise result there: Typescript applied the typings of `jasminewd2`, not `jasmine` and therefore, the autocompletion of vscode told me that there would be a promise as result

Comment: That makes sense!  In `jasminewd2` everything is a promise since the code runs on the remote process.